# How do I programmatically load an order by its properties?

Tags: 8, commerce

I know how to load an order by its ID using `\Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::load($order_id)`. I added a custom field (*Token ID*) to the orders.

How can I load the orders knowing the value of that field? If I want to get the state of the order, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Is that custom field added field from managed Fields or you just programmatically adding it?

Comment: I added field from manage fields. Field name "field_token_id".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do this is by using by `loadByProperties` based on Token field:

```
$orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('commerce_order')
  ->loadByProperties(['field_token_id' => 'TOKEN VALUE']);
$order = reset($orders);
$state = $order->get('state')->value;
$total_price = $order->getTotalprice()->getNumber();
$currency = $order->getTotalprice()->getCurrencyCode();
```

Here assuming token as a unique value.

Comment: Similarly I tried to get total price by $total_price = $order->get('total_price')->value; but it doesnt work. But when i use $order-getTotalprice(); i am getting price with currency code. What should i type if i just want the number/price.?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Did you know how to solve this ? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/269311/how-to-load-promotion-amount-from-order-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 5):

you will need to use Drupal EntityQuery to get the order id and load order using its id, the following code might help :

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_order')
->condition('field_token_id.value', VALUE_OF_TOKEN);
$order_ids = $query->execute();
foreach($order_ids as $order_id) {
  \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::load($order_id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... :) Yes.. I am able to load the order. I am getting an array. Now how can i get each field in that corresponding order. Suppose i want to store "signature_id" in a variable which is also a custom field in that order. How can i get that.

Comment: @RifasAli I edited the above code to show how you can get the order state. I prefer the use of entityQuery to the entityTypeManager mentioned above since it is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the Most efficient and Fast way to get all the Orders is

```
$orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->loadMultiple();
```

if you want to get the Completed Orders then you can use the loadByProperties() as like:

```
$orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->loadByProperties(['state' => 'completed']);
```